# Passing class as parameter causes "is not newable" error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass a class as a parameter to some function, that will instantiate this class and return it. Here is my code:

```
module A.Views {
  export class View { ... }
}

module A.App {
  export class MyApp {
    ...
    registerView(viewKlass:A.Views.View):void
    {
        var test = new viewKlass;
    } 
  }
}
```

When i'm trying to compile this, i'm getting:

```
(...): Value of type 'Views.View' is not newable.
```

What am I doing wrong?

If a newable type value is an object constructor how do i pass the constructor function at runtime?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

We need something to say `typeof(MyClass)` to distinguish objects from classes in function signatures.

Anyway, you can actually solve you problem by using constructor type signature.
Considering this class:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor (private name: string) {
    }
}
```

To pass that class as a type that you can then instantiate in a function, you actually have to duplicate the class constructor signature like this:

```
function sample(MyClass: new (name: string) => MyClass) {
    var obj = new MyClass("hello");
}
```

**EDIT :**
There is a simple solution found on codeplex:

You have to create an interface for your class like this:

```
interface IMyClass {
    new (name: string): MyClass;
}
```

Then, use it in your function signature:

```
function sample(MyClass: IMyClass) {
    var obj = new MyClass("hello");
}
```

Comment: function sample(MyClass: typeof MyClass) should do it.

Comment: If you don't know the constructor arguments, you could also use `new (...args: any[]): MyClass` inside your interface.

Comment: Actually, `function sample(MyClass: typeof MyClass)` from Corey comment could **only** work for non-abstract classes. To do the same thing with [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes), `function sample(MyClass: new (name: string) => MyClass)` is a better choice.

Answer (score 47):

To supplement the other answers; I have a utility type I keep around to ensure a generic parameter/field is a class/newable:

```
/* new T() */
export type Newable<T> = { new (...args: any[]): T; };
```

You can then ensure you get a class constructor:

```
class MyApp<TViewBase>
{
  register<TView extends TViewBase>(view: Newable<TView>) { 
  }
}
```

the `Newable<T>` approach works where `typeof T` --where `T` is a generic type-- does not.

For example:  `register<T extends TViewBase>(view: typeof T)` results in the following error:

> > [ts] 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: This is a great answer, could you please explain a little bit more how it works?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and honestly, included in TypeScript. This is definitely superior to trying to identify the exact signature of the class' constructor.

Comment: Awesome answer  This helped me with passing a class constructor of a generic child of an abstract class too.

Comment: I think if you replace `any[]` with `never[]` it will make it harder to erroneously call the constructor when you don't really know what arguments it requires. TS will still let you call it with _no_ args, unfortunately, but if you try to pass any args to it you'll get a type-checking error when using `never[]` (when using `any[]`, TS would let you pass anything you want when invoking the constructor).

Answer (score 32):

Try this:

```
export class MyApp {
    registerView(viewKlass: typeof A.Views.View): void {
        var test = new viewKlass();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 26):

There are 2 ways to pass classes in TypeScript. If you:

- **know the superclass of the class you're passing through** (already recommended by Corey Alix):

  ```
  class MyClass extends MySuperClass{ }

  makeMyClass(classRef: typeof MySuperclass) {
      return new classRef();
  }

  makeMyClass(MyClass);
  ```
- **know the signature of the class's constructor function**:

  ```
  class MyClass {
      constructor(arg: string) {}
  }

  makeMyClass(classRef: { new(arg: string) }) {
      return new classRef('hello');
  }

  makeMyClass(MyClass);
  ```

Comment: What if MySuperclass is an abstract class? I cannot use typeof MySuperclass then, because it's not possible to call the constructor on the abstract class.

Comment: I'd also like to know that!

Answer (score 15):

in case you use Angular, they have [implemented](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cfed0c0cf1238e5ad931598ce04c32f8c9a75143/packages/core/src/interface/type.ts#L35) `Type`, its similar to the [Meirion Hughes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983481/2519073):

```
import {Type} from '@angular/core';

export class MyApp {
  ...
  registerView(viewKlass: Type<A.Views.View>):void
  {
      var test = new viewKlass();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Something alike is implemented in `@nestjs/common` as well with the same purpose.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but here goes:

```
...
registerView(viewKlass: { new(): A.Views.View }):void
{
    var test = new viewKlass();
}
```

Answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311757/2365824).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your situation, the three solution bellow might not be enough:

1. `myClass: new (name: string) => MyClass`
2. `interface IMyClass {
   new (name: string): MyClass;
   };
   myClass: IMyClass`
3. `myClass: typeof MyClass`

There are cases where you would like to call some **static** methods like `myClass.someMethod()`. `1` and `2` won't allow you to do that (and pls never use any in your app) because they don't know about that method.

Or there are cases when you want to have `MyClass` as an **abstract** class and create an instance of myClass with `let instance = new myClass`. In that case, `3` will fail.

What I do in these cases is to create a special type for `MyClass` that will solve the issues I highlighted above, which looks something like this:

`type MyClassContructor<T extends MyClass> = typeof MyClass & Constructor<T>;`

BTW. Don't forget to add return types to your methods so you get proper intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do `typeof {Class}`

in your case

```
 registerView(viewKlass: typeof A.Views.View):void
    {
        var test = new viewKlass();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the gist - a slight change makes it all work fine. In the example below, we "new up" the `TestView` to pass in the concrete test view, rather than trying to new it within the method.

```
module V.Views {
   export class View {
      public someVar: any;
      // the presence of constructor doesn't affect the error triggering
   }
}

module V.App {
    export class Application {
        public registerView(url: string, viewKlass: V.Views.View): void
        {
            var test = viewKlass;
        }
    }
}

var app = new V.App.Application;

class TestView extends V.Views.View {
}

class TestView2 extends V.Views.View {
}

app.registerView('', new TestView())
app.registerView('content/view/:slug/', new TestView2())
```

Comment: Can you post your full example code - I've tested my code in the Playground and don't get the error - so your code must contain something different.

Comment: But this doesn't solves my problem. I want to pass a class not an object. :)

Comment: If you want to instantiate the object inside the `registerView` method, you'll have to pass a string, not a `viewKlass`. i.e. `viewKlass: V.Views.View` would have to be `viewKlass: string` and then you could call `var test = <V.Views.View>new viewKlass();`