# Generic and typeof T in the parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

In TypeScript I can define the type of a variable as the type of a class. For example:

```
class MyClass { ... }

let myVar: typeof MyClass = MyClass;
```

Now I want to use this with a generic class, something like this:

```
class MyManager<T> {
    constructor(cls: typeof T) { ... }
    /* some other methods, which uses instances of T */
}

let test = new MyManager(MyClass); /* <MyClass> should be implied by the parameter */
```

So, I want to give my manager class another class (its constructor), because the manager needs to retreive static information associated with the *class*.

When compiling my code, it says that it cannot find name 'T', where my constructor is.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this type of constructors: `{ new (): ClassType }`.

```
class MyManager<T> {
    private cls: { new(): T };

    constructor(cls: { new(): T }) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    createInstance(): T {
        return new this.cls();
    }
}

class MyClass {}

let test = new MyManager(MyClass);
let a = test.createInstance();
console.log(a instanceof MyClass); // true
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyManager%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09private%20cls%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0A%09%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(cls%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%09%09this.cls%20%3D%20cls%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09createInstance()%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20new%20this.cls()%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20MyManager(MyClass)%3B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20test.createInstance()%3B%0Aconsole.log(a%20instanceof%20MyClass)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true))

---

#### Edit

The proper way to describe a class type in typescript is using the following:

```
{ new(): Class }
```

For example in the typescript [lib.d.ts `ArrayConstructor`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1243):

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    new (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    new <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    new <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    isArray(arg: any): arg is Array<any>;
    readonly prototype: Array<any>;
}
```

Here you have 3 different ctor signatures plus a bunch of static functions.
In your case you can also define it like:

```
interface ClassConstructor<T> {
    new(): T;
}

class MyManager<T> {
    private cls: ClassConstructor<T>;

    constructor(cls: ClassConstructor<T>) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    createInstance(): T {
        return new this.cls();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that abvious what `{ new(): T }` is about, especially because the constructor is defined as `constructor()` and one would rather expect something like just `T`, `typeof T` or whatever.

Comment: It's a standard way to define a class type/ctor, check me revised answer for more info.

Comment: @NitzanTomer How would you write the constructor to allow for `let test = new MyManager(Array<MyClass>);` ? or `...MyManager(MyClass[]);`

Comment: @GFoley83 How about: `constructor(cls: MyClassConstrcutor<T>[])`

Comment: @NitzanTomer What I was looking for was `constructor(cls: { new (...args: any[]): T } [])`

Comment: @GFoley83 Yeah, that's what I wrote just with a type alias and without ctor arguments