# Method parameter should be subclass of given class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript2.0

I am struggling with defining a method to take subclasses of a base class correctly.

```
handle(content: AbstractClass)
```

Calling it directly with an inherited class leads to **Argument of type 'ConcreteClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractClass'**.

I have tried it with an interface, similar result **Argument of type 'typeof ConcreteClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interface'**

```
class AbstractClass implements Interface

handle(content: Interface)
```

I have found a question to a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38311672/390177) but the solution also don't helps me.

```
interface ClassConstructor<T extends AbstractClass> {
  new(): T;
}

abstract class AbstractClass {
  private test: string;

  constructor(value: string) {}
}

class B extends AbstractClass {
  private test2: string;

  constructor(value: string, value2: number) {
    super(modal);
  }
}

class S1 {
  show(content: ClassConstructor<AbstractClass>) {}

  b() {
    this.a(B);
  }
}
```

On [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ClassConstructor%3CT%20extends%20A%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20new()%3A%20T%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20private%20test%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20private%20test2%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor(value%3A%20string%2C%20value2%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(value)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20S1%20%7B%0A%20%20a(content%3A%20ClassConstructor%3CA%3E)%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20b()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.a(B)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

I want to achieve that the method `show` can take every implementation of the *AbstractClass* regardless how it is defined f.e. different constructors and similar.
I am using it in combination with Angular and Angular resolves dependencies via the constructor.

How can I do this with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the signatures of the constructors don't match.

This works:

```
interface ClassConstructor<T extends A> {
    new(value: string): T;
}

class B extends A {
    private test2: string;

    constructor(value: string) {
        super(value);
    }
}

class S1 {
    a(content: ClassConstructor<B>) {}
    b() {
        this.a(B);
    }
}
```

Now the different constructors share the same signature.

Comment: So it is not possible to use if the constructors are different?

Comment: If the constructors are different then you probably need a different solution. What is your exact use case? In the code you provided so far you can just change it to `a(content: { new (value: string, value2: number): B }) {}` and everything works out well. There's no real need for the `ClassConstructor`. So please update your question with your real scenario, then you might get an answer that helps you

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope it is more clear now. I have a base class which will be extended on different ways and with different constructors caused by different dependencies. I want to achieve that the given method can take every implementation.

Comment: You can change the `ClassConstructor` to have this: `new(...args: any[]): T;`. That should match all of the different signatures