# flowtype: $Subtype and typeof fail when used in generic types

Tags: flowtype

It appears that class types in flow always refer to instances of that class and one uses `typeof` to refer to the actual class itself. So, if I want a variable to refer to a subclass (not an instance) of a base class, I can do:

```
class MyBaseClass {}
class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass {}
let a: $Subtype<MyBaseClass> = MySubClass; // fails
let b: $Subtype<MyBaseClass> = new MySubClass(); // works, but I don't want this.
let c: $Subtype<typeof MyBaseClass> = MySubClass; // works! Ok, we're good
```

However, I can't seem to do this with type parameters! For example, the following:

```
type GenericSubclass<T> = $Subtype<typeof T>;
// fails with `^ identifier `T`. Could not resolve name`
```

If I try the following Typescript trick (see [Generic and typeof T in the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311672/generic-and-typeof-t-in-the-parameters)), it also fails:

```
type ValidSubclass<T> = { new(): T };
const c: ValidSubclass<BaseClass> = MySubClass;
// fails with: property `new`. Property not found in statics of MySubClass
```

Note that I tried `new`, `__proto__` and `constructor`.

What gives? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typeof MyBaseClass
```

is

```
Class<MyBaseClass>
```

so you can do

```
type GenericSubclass<T> = $Subtype<Class<T>>;
```