# new(...args) => T syntax

Tags: typescript

I've come across the [following type annotation on a function parameter](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/02/union-type-constraints/):

```
typeFilter : new(...args) => T
```

where `T` is a generic parameter on the function.

What does `new(...args)` mean in this context, and where is it documented?

Comment: It defines a constructor type, something where `new typefilter(...)` would produce an instance of `T`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311672/generic-and-typeof-t-in-the-parameters/38311757#38311757, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13407036/3001761

Comment: And `...args` - [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters). To sum up - constructor of `T` taking any parameters

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was hoping for a link to the official documentation.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** `new(...args) => T` represents constructor of `T` taking any parameters.

`new` describes "static" part of a class/function, meaning it is a constructor and consumer can create new instance of `T` using `new` keyword. Example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).

As for `...args` - these are [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes)

> Rest parameters are treated as a boundless number of optional parameters. When passing arguments for a rest parameter, you can use as many as you want; you can even pass none

Comment: Just as a note: A technique called mixins (something like polymorphism) use such annotations.