# What does this mean: public sub<T>(params: { new(...args: any[]): T }): Observable<T>

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below is Typescript code. I don't understand what is a type of `params` parameter?

```
export class SomeService {
    ...
    public subscribe<T>(params: { new(...args: any[]): T }): Observable<T> {

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Can someone explain to me what this part means `{ new(...args: any[]): T }`?

**UPDATE**:

`params` has to be Type. Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet%3CT%3E(params%3A%20%7B%20new(...args)%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20params%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Button%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet(Greeter))%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B)

Like this: `someService.subscribe(String);` or `someService.subscribe(SomeClass);`

Comment: @rlemon, thanks. The link is not that clear for a newbie like me. But link inside the link is very clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311672/generic-and-typeof-t-in-the-parameters/38311757#38311757

Comment: Every line of typescript code I see makes me hate it more. I consider that completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is telling you that `params` must be constructible by any number of parameters, which becomes a `T`.