# Type of angular components

Tags: angular, typescript, type-safety

Can I refer to angular component class as a type? I see Ionic uses `any` for components. Is it possible in Typescript to declare an argument type, that expects only component classes?

I saw this question, but components don't have anything in common in constructors:
 [Passing class as parameter causes "is not newable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802317/passing-class-as-parameter-causes-is-not-newable-error)

Comment: What about the components is it that you care about in this context? Could you use an existing interface like `OnInit` for your needs? In general, components are written as unrelated classes with interfaces mixed in as required.

Comment: I care about classes wrapped in Component decorator.

Comment: But that doesn't give them a type, it just attaches some metadata. So, again, what do you actually care about? Are you trying to call methods on them? Accessing properties? Think duck typing - what's the quack?

Comment: I am passing them to a router. It renders component. So it needs to be a Component.

Comment: There's only so many ways to say that's not a type. So:

Comment: AFAIK the only way to do that would be to override the object prototype with something like getName. I don't know if Angular or Ionic does this. I'd find it useful if it was baked in somewhere. Ionic lazy loading tabbed pages with deep linking... See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript

Comment: just define an interface `RouteComponent` and make all relevent components implement it

Comment: An interface would affect only instances of a class, not a class. It would also involve adding a property to every component. I guess the only way is to write a decorator or override angular's one. I was hoping metadata somehow changes the class but looks like it stored outside of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out this is not possible in TypeScript right now. Decorators cannot change type of a class, that means they are invisible for a type system.
More info can be found here:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26347
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Answer (score 9):

There is `ComponentType<T>`.
Maybe it will help.

```
import { ComponentType } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
```

Answer (score 3):

If they are components that are created dynamically, Angular provides the ComponentRef class.

See here:  https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef

A statically declared component won't have this class. Although, you can pass around Component identifiers as an untyped variable as needed, as long as you import them into the relevant components / services. If you're using dependency injection, i.e, to inject a component instance into its host directive, the 'type' would just be whatever its name is, like so -

```
 import { Directive } from '@angular/core'
 import { MyNavigatorComponent } from '../components/my-nav.component'

 constructor (private navigator: MyNavigatorComponent) {
```

Answer (score 2):

**From: https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef**

The Following represents a type that a Component or other object is an instance of.

An example of a Type is MyCustomComponent class, which in JavaScript is represented by the MyCustomComponent constructor function.

**Code sample:**

```
import { Type } from "@angular/core";

export type MyDynamicComponentType = Type<any>;
```