# What is the type of an Angular 13 component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a component that receives another component through an input which you can see [in this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-apqkdb?file=src/app/parent-component/parent.component.ts).  If you look at the `@Input()` of the `ParentComponent` you'll see it's defined as

```
@Input() ComponentToEmbed : eComponentType<Component>;
```

I came across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823393/type-of-angular-components) from 4 years ago, which suggested using `ComponentType<T>`, which is what made me try it.  However, in my Angular 13 app, there is no such a thing as `ComponentType` being found when I begin typing.  I looked on the doc pages and didn't see anything mentioning `ComponentType<T>`.  What should I do to type the `@Input()` properly?

Answer (score 2):

`ComponentType<T>` is part of [Angular Material CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#ComponentType)

```
/** Interface that can be used to generically type a class. */
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Comment: aahhhh ok that explains why I can't find it anywhere in Angulars code or docs, that's a huge help lol.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you stackblitz example, it looks like `Type<Component>` should do the trick.

```js
import { Type } from '@angular/core';
...

@Input() ComponentToEmbed : Type <Component>;
...
```

Comment: This works in my `ParentComponent` but if you look at my `AppComponent` in the stackblitz where I initially import it to pass into the `ParentComponent` it says the component isn't assignable to `Type<Component>` because it doesn't have properties in common with `Component`.  So in my `AppComponent` I have to leave it as type `any`.  Would you happen to know why that is?

Comment: I created a more generic approach, but it's hard to make it type-strict or type-safe, since there is no common prototype for all Components, since `Component` is not a base class component but rather just a decorator or in simpler terms: a helper function. Therefore there is no way to make some field that would only accept Component constructor functions without introducing a new base class for all children components. However, you can make sure that the passed value is a constructor function, and using some conditional typing even to narrow it more precisely.

Comment: The example I mentioned above is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7uqhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent-component%2Fparent.component.ts