# Declare class type with TypeScript (pass class as parameter)

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

so I have a function which accepts different constructors, like so:

```
export class SomeSuperClass {
 ...
}

export class A extends SomeSuperClass {
 ...
}

export class B extends SomeSuperClass {
 ...
}


const foo = function(Clazz: SomeSuperClass){

  const v = new Clazz();

}

foo(A);  // pass the class itself
foo(B);  // pass the class itself
```

the problem is that `SomeSuperClass` means that `Clazz` will be an instance of `SomeSuperClass`, but not `SomeSuperClass` itself.

I tried something stupid like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
   const foo = function(Clazz: SomeSuperClass.constructor){

      const v = new Clazz();

   }
```

what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mentioned, what you are looking to is how to describe class constructor and not the instance. It can be achieved by:

```
const foo = function(ctor: new() => SomeSuperClass) {
    ...
}
```

Or alternatively (same result in this case):

```
const foo = function(ctor: typeof SomeSuperClass) {
    ...
}
```

This also requires `A` and `B` to have parameterless constructors

Answer (score 5):

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802317/passing-class-as-parameter-causes-is-not-newable-error), it looks like the only way to do this is like so:

```
interface ISomeSuperClass {
    new (): SomeSuperClass;
}
```

where foo would then become:

```
   const foo = function(Clazz: ISomeSuperClass){

      const v = new Clazz();

   }
```

This seems kind of weird, but it compiles.

Comment: yes the interface is a better choice because it can be implemented by multiple classes and you are not passing any concrete class as argument

Comment: If you can add an answer explaining that in full, I will upvote

Comment: Classes must have an interface to describe the members there are static, which is the case of the constructor, and an interface for the intances members. You will find the full explanation if you look for  _**Difference between the static and instance sides of classes**_ in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

The following way worked for me.

VarName: typeof ClassName;

Where, typeof is the Javascript keyword.

Comment: `typeof` in that position is not the JavaScript keyword, it's a TypeScript keyword