# declare class as parameter to call static function

Tags: typescript

similar to [declare-class-type-with-typescript-pass-class-as-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484010/declare-class-type-with-typescript-pass-class-as-parameter) but not work in this case

```js
class Super {
  static hello(): void;
}

class SubA extends Super {
    // edited
    constructor(arg: string) { super(); } 
}

class SubB extends Super {
    // edited
    constructor(arg: string) { super(); }
}

function saySomething(cls: typeof Super) {
    cls.hello()
}

// turn out
// Argument of type 'typeof SubA' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Super'.
// with vscode
saySomething(SubA)

saySomething(SubB)
```

I wanna to pass sub class of [sequlize.Model](https://sequelize.org/master/) as a parameter exactly

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I have written a minimal reproducible example in my answer but you should do it in your question. Your code works as is, the problem is actually related to the constructor functions and it doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: I write the pseudo-code from my original code without testing, sorry for that and I'll be more rigorous next time I ask a question. I just edited the example in description, hope the next one that visit this question won't be confused. Thanks for your kindly help  @GuerricP

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for taking my observation in account 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example of your problem:

```
class Super {
  static hello(): void {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

class SubA extends Super {
  constructor(arg: string) { super(); }
}

class SubB extends Super {
  constructor(arg: string) { super(); }
}

function saySomething(cls: typeof Super) {
  cls.hello()
}

// turn out
// Argument of type 'typeof SubA' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Super'.
// with vscode
saySomething(SubA);

saySomething(SubB);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJ2gbwFDWhALmPgJbDQAWyIIA9gBQCUAXNAG43EAmmOu0wNAHYQaIZADpaAczoByStRqyGAbl4BfLJqyhIMBACMAgtGQAPfMkGd9SND1wDh%20VPGD4aqOmFRSWBVGJBKQZMPDsvVWhNbV0oOHgDACFTCysbBJR0bEchALcPLx8-PBcgkLCICMYVaK0sLAAzeEF3YiE8MABPWBoAW2R8cnK6UAgWfC6UGkbMtFCc-hAIcQVaRnqsAHot6Hx4VEFoGnh8bd2jX3gBwXxj2cmUaFlH5BmE41loYhhBGju9MQpIIwAYxHsaNBED4wANLOh3q9nq93ggsrJxOdoAB3YhDNgQAScZBYCDdXpw4bBOiGIyqBpknr9QZUmSGJKqIA)

The problem occurs because a constructor function of an extending class doesn't necessarily take the same arguments, so it's not assignable to the `Super` class constructor.

As you don't need the constructor function at all but only the `static` properties (attached to the constructor), you could use a `NoConstructor` helper type in order to keep only the keys and remove the constructor function from the `typeof Super` type:

```
class Super {
  static hello(): void {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

class SubA extends Super {
  constructor(arg: string) { super(); }
}

class SubB extends Super {
  constructor(arg: string) { super(); }
}

type NoConstructor<T> = Pick<T, keyof T>;

function saySomething(cls: NoConstructor<typeof Super>) {
  cls.hello(); // Works
}

saySomething(SubA); // Works

saySomething(SubB); // Works
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJ2gbwFDWhALmPgJbDQAWyIIA9gBQCUAXNAG43EAmmOu0wNAHYQaIZADpaAczoByStRqyGAbl4BfLJqyhIMBACMAgtGQAPfMkGd9SND1wDh%20VPGD4aqOmFRSWBVGJBKQZMPDsvVWhNbV0oOHgDACFTCysbBJR0bEchALcPLx8-PBcgkLCICMYVaK0sLHwATxRoADkaAGE8lwLPAB4AFQA%20aABeaAAFUgBrIYAaaBnkJpoAM2gRtSw1%20EF3YiE8MCbYGgBbZHxycrpQCBYO7udXdwHmlHXMtGHQnP4QBBxApaDV6lgICczpdrrdDEZVA1IacLlcbsE6IYkqogA)

Comment: It works! Thanks